# How should I "think" when I am creating higher order components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a nightmare trying to figure out how to approach a higher order component. I get how they work (I hope), but as soon as I begin writing my code I stop at here:

```
const HeadlineHOC = WrappedComponent => props => {
  if (props.articleHasArrived) {
    return <WrappedComponent { ...props } article={ props.article } />
  }
};
```

I also know how to make that return a class component and add a state instead of a regular functional component but that's almost the same exact thing. Can't I just create a class component and apply a state there anyway, instead of having to go make the extra step in creating the HOC? But thats about as useful I can get when creating a useful higher order component. But its a bum that you can just do that if/else conditional render with a normal function component without the need of making it an HOC. I've read tons of examples, tons of tutorials, tons of explanations why higher order components are good for their examples.

The problem is that I only know that a higher order component is the right thing to do in *their* situation. But how do I *think* of creating useful higher order components for my components? How can I acquire that mindset of coming across a problem and *immediately knowing* that a HOC is the only way to do it? How do you guys approach higher order components as a problem-solving thing?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I guess to put it in a slightly different perspective: how to solve problems with a higher order component? Because in my perspective anything a HOC can do can be done in a regular component. Thats what confuses me the most

Comment: No actual problem is described at Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan Abramov probably explains it best in [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750). I would read through this to get a grasp of why and how to use '*Higher Order Components*'